# How do I search within variables on Yaml files for my jinja 2

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

How do I check for a string within a variable, and return another part of that variable?

I have the following within my host_vars

```yaml
vrfs:
  - { vrf: vrf-sitea, enabled: y,}
  - { vrf: vrf-siteb, enabled: n,}
  - { vrf: vrf-sitec, enabled: y,}
  - { vrf: vrf-sited, enabled: y,}
```

And I am trying to figure out how I search a string within it, and when that is matched, check if `y` is there.

For example, if the `vrf = vrf-siteb`, then see if `enabled` is `y`.

I want to be able to make `vrf-siteb` a variable but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) and the [JMESPath query language](https://jmespath.org/) for this :

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "{{ vrfs | json_query('[?enabled == `y`].vrf') }}"
      vars:
        vrfs:
          - { vrf: vrf-sitea, enabled: y,}
          - { vrf: vrf-siteb, enabled: n,}
          - { vrf: vrf-sitec, enabled: y,}
          - { vrf: vrf-sited, enabled: y,}
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "vrf-sitea",
        "vrf-sitec",
        "vrf-sited"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters to get the right object with `selectattr` and then get the `enabled` value with `map`:

```
{{ vrfs | selectattr('vrf', 'vrf-siteb') | map(attribute='enabled') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary. For example, use [items2dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#items2dict-filter)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        vrfs_dict: "{{ vrfs|items2dict(key_name='vrf', value_name='enabled') }}"
    - debug:
        var: vrfs_dict
```

gives

```yaml
  vrfs_dict:
    vrf-sitea: y
    vrf-siteb: n
    vrf-sitec: y
    vrf-sited: y
```

Then the searching is trivial. For example

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: vrfs_dict['vrf-siteb']
```

gives

```yaml
  vrfs_dict['vrf-siteb']: n
```

Because of the dash "-" inside the names, the keys are not [valid variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names). As a result, dotted format can't be used

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: vrfs_dict.vrf-siteb
```

gives

```yaml
  vrfs_dict.vrf-siteb: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```